# can't setting a array or object to html5 web storage?

Tags: javascript, html, storage

i'm new to html5 web storage

setting to a web storage is easy.

```
sessionStorage.someKey = 'someValue';
```

but when i setting a array or object to a key like

```
sessionStorage.name = ['abc','def'];
typeof sessionStorage.name;
//output "string"
//a object is the same
```

so how to use array or object in web storage? or there is a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used data structure in the past like this by using JSON. Here is a sample...

```
var data = { First: "abc", Second: "def" };
var jsData = JSON.stringify(data);
window.sessionStorage.setItem("key1", jsData);
```

Then you can get the data like so...

```
var jsData = window.sessionStorage.getItem("key1");
var data = JSON.parse(jsData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
function saveInSession(key, val) {
    sessionStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(val);
}

function getFromSession(key) {
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage[key]);
}
```

You would need to include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) in your page to ensure cross-browser support for `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 0):

For safety reasons I put everything in a JSON encoded Base64 encoded string. Maybe Base64 is not needed but the safer the better.

Example just with JSON:

```
sessionStorage.name = JSON.stringify(['abc','def']);
typeof JSON.parse(sessionStorage.name);
```

It will be an array.